# Packaging ActiveX Controls with Wix MSI

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, activex

I need to create MSI using Wix. My application has **Active X control**. When any user gets connected or visit the URL on the web my application needs to be installed in the user machine.
The path where I need to install is `C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\CONFLICT.xx` and this folder should contain the file ATL80.dll, app.dll, MSVCP80.dll MSVCR80.dll.
I saw few articles but got confused with them. please let me know how to start for this and what steps i need to follow in order to make MSI.

Comment: Please show us what you did.  Show some effort

Comment: Would you mind adding a comment to illustrate the solution you came up with?

Comment: I followed exactly the instruction given in the below comment by Glytzhkof. And it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more to this: [Packaging ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974(v=vs.85).aspx).

Essentially a **web page** will request a **signed cab** to be downloaded and installed via a **CODEBASE URL**, like this:

(sample from the Microsoft article linked above)

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:dcf0768D-ba7a-101a-b57a-0000c0c3ed5f"
    CODEBASE="http://webserver/time.cab"
    ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH=270 HEIGHT=26 ID="T1"><PARAM NAME="Interval" VALUE=1000>
    <PARAM NAME="Enabled" VALUE=1></OBJECT>
```

The **requested cab** is downloaded (**time.cab**), and installed (standard Microsoft cab installation / extraction). The next time the web page is opened the Active X control should work as expected. That's the normal case (admin rights are required for this to work). A successful install here can be captured and packaged as an MSI. Heavy cleanup is required though, due to all the certificates that are involved to complete the install. None of the certificates are required in the MSI as I recall, since an MSI runs with admin / elevated rights and dump files straight in the folder. Quite a security problem if you ask me, but these cabs are rarely deployed this way. Unsigned cab files won't work though (unless IE is customized).

The **CONFLICT folder** that is created in this users case indicates that there are discrepancies between the installed files from the cab and the version of those files specified and expected by the web page. This causes IE to trigger a new CAB download. Upon discovering the same files already exist in `C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\` a new CONFLICT sub folder is created each time, and the user gets prompted for a new Active X installation every time the page is opened.

You must work to resolve the file versions specified by the web page and the versions of the files found in the cab. These versions must match. I can't recall all the details, but it might be that all that is checked is the CAB file version:

([Sample from this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533576(v=vs.85).aspx))

```
<object id="CommonDialog1" width="32" HEIGHT="32"
    classid="CLSID:F9043C85-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB"
    codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb5/comdlg32.cab
    #Version=1,0,0,0">
</object>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a nice and explanation.It gave me basic idea for proceeding ahead.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question about the Visual C++ redistributables because ActiveX controls installed from a web page don't need installing with an MSI. If that's all you're doing then the short answer is that you get hold of the VC 2005 redistributable and run it, this kind of thing:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387

This installs the C++ support files like ATL80.dll etc in the right places and it just works. You don't get much say in where they go:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316(v=vs.80).aspx

It's dangerous to have your private versions of those Dlls because there are security fixes for them, and if you have a private copy that the MS security updates can't find and fix then you effectively become responsible for maintaining them on the client systems.

On the other hand, I can't be sure from your question if you have a separate MSI file with a lot of other stuff in it (not the ActiveX) that you want to install by having people download it.

Comment: In addition to the runtime issues, it's the quirky world of Active X cab deployment via web pages: [Packaging ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974(v=vs.85).aspx). See my answer, it might lack some details.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but the point is that there seem to be no WiX or MSI issues here at all, and the question seems to be about getting the VC++ runtimes onto the system. It's not obviously clear, but I think maybe he knows how to package AX controls in a web page and just needs the VC_++ runtime on the system. An update to the question might resolve that question.

Comment: The CONFLICT folder only shows up when something is wrong in the cab installation. He should try to capture this install instead of using Wix.

Comment: Just to wrap this up (I came across this again today): ActiveX installs can be captured and redistributed as an MSI in order to avoid all users having to install the ActiveX control manually with admin rights. I have done this several times, and know that it works (unless the handling of ActiveX installations changes in the web-browser). Effectively the signed ActiveX is verified on first launch / install and installation proceeds if you have admin rights. If you capture this process and the web page asks for the version of the file you install, all prompts disappear and the control is loaded.